# Update data from SQL without refreshing the page

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, ajax

I'm building the online score asp.net web application. Score points are saved in the SQL database. Is there any way to update the labels without refreshing the page? I tried UpdatePanel but without success. Is it even possible to load data asynchronously from SQL server? From what I understand AJAX scripts(which I believe UpdatePanel also uses) run only locally in the browser (is that right ?). So it really does not make much sense to me. Any ideas ?

Comment: `AJAX scripts run only locally in the browser (is that right?)` The J in AJAX stands for Javascript, which does indeed run on your visitor's browser. However, this Javascript can make calls to other pages on your website, and retrieve live scores without updating the page. This is how google suggests search terms in real-time without reloading the page.

Comment: @safiron you gotta check your implementation of update panel , however check this link it will help you http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-ajax.htm

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use Ajax with JSON instead of UpdatePanel. UdatePanel is really a post back to the server which goes through the full page life cycle so Ajax with JSON is much faster performance wise.

http://encosia.com/are-you-making-these-3-common-aspnet-ajax-mistakes/

For the JSON/Ajax call you can create a webmethod in your code-behind and then call that. Look at below URL for a simple example on how to do it. The example is for getting the data but you can use the webmethod to update

http://deebujacob.blogspot.com/2012/01/aspnet-ajax-web-method-call-using.html

You can also call a WCF or Web API service instead of Web Method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You don't need to use a web method. You can call an entirely separate service, which can be written with WCF or ASP.NET Web API.

Comment: I agree with using a webmethod or httphandler.

Comment: Yes it could be WCF or Web API. I have updated my answer for that.

Comment: I tend to use a generic handler in these situations.